# 'nc' command stopping even with -k option

Tags: linux, netcat

I am trying to listen continuously to port 5000 and print the first line of message but the program is stopping after one iteration. I am using the following command for it -

```
nc -k -l 5000 | head -n 1
```

I have used -k option with nc but still the program stops after one iteration. What is the problem in this command?

Answer (score 2):

It is not so simple. The second `nc` could be started only after the *full* run of the previous. But it can't be done, because `nc` has a bug: it can't detect if the remote side closes its socket. Thus, the first nc never stops, thus the second can't be started.

The developers of the `nc` say, that it is an inherent problem of the TCP protocol, my opinion is that they haven't right [but it is only my opinion].

If you want to do practically a script listening on a TCP port, a working solution were to put this `head -1` into a script, and calling this script from an inetd.

Some trickier hack could work as well, for example, *killing* the first `nc` after the first line, so:

```
nc -k -l 5000|(read;echo $REPLY;killall -9 nc)
```

Imho this tools aren't enough stable for productive environment, although they can be very funny. :-)